# SpringBoot Security antMatchers не работают в паре

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Элементарная задача.

Мучаюсь третий день. Что только не пробовал.  Настраиваю **ConfigSecurity**.

Мне нужно, чтобы **ADMIN**  имел доступ ко всем урлам **API**.
  А **DOCTOR**  имел доступ только к **api/person/**.

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()

          .antMatchers("/", "/css", "/js").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
          .antMatchers("/api/person/**").hasRole(DOCTOR.name())

               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic();

}
```

Эти два  **antMatchers**  как ни крути  **не работают в паре**!!!!

Если первым стоит 
 `.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())`

То ДОКТОР ничего не видит  -  **"status": 403,**

А вот АДМИН всё видит прекрасно.

Меняю их местами

```
       .antMatchers("/api/person/**").hasRole(DOCTOR.name())
       .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
```

Доктор видит своих персонов, 
а вот АДМИН уже не видит тех же персонов - "status": 403.

Другие урлы ADMIN из API видит без проблем.

ГДе моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `.hasRole(ADMIN.name())` использовать `.hasAuthority("ADMIN")`;

То есть попробуйте реализовать в вашей программе следующий вариант:

```java
.antMatchers("/api/person/**").hasAuthority("DOCTOR")
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

Comment: Не помогло.  К тому же , я думаю , что надо ставить DOCTOR.name() вместо DOCTOR.   Но всё равно не помогает.

Comment: @YuraP. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819556/8992586

Comment: Спасибо Antonio112009 .    Сработало !!!

Comment: @YuraP. отметите тогда мой ответ как верный?

Comment: С удовольствием отмечу. Но как это сделать?  Отметить можно ответы , но не комментарии.  Если Вы оформите ответ как ОТВЕТ, а не как комментарий  - тут же отмечу как привильный.